# Groovy program- convert string to xml

Tags: groovy

convert the string to xml format, could you please correct the below logic.

```
    class Demo {
       static void main(String[] args) {
         String keyList = """name=raj role=IT"""
          def splitList = keyList.split("\n")
           for (String item : splitList) {
             // println(item)
             def splitData = item.split("=") 
              for (String value : splitData)
              {
                  println(value)
                  println("<"+value.getAt(0)+">"+value.getAt(1)+"/<"+value.getAt(0)+">")
              }
          }
       }
    }
 output:
        <name>raj</name>
        <role>IT</name>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Creating XML like that is fraught with problems, and you will 100% generate invalid XML even if you get it working...

Better to use the classes provided to generate valid XML, for example this:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

String keyList = """name=raj role=IT
name=tim role=Solutions"""
def sw = new StringWriter()
new MarkupBuilder(sw).root {
    keyList.eachLine {line ->
        person {
            line.split("\\s").each {
                def (key, value) = it.split("=", 2)
                "$key"(value)
            }
        }
    }
}
println(sw.toString())
```

Which prints:

```
<root>
  <person>
    <name>raj</name>
    <role>IT</role>
  </person>
  <person>
    <name>tim</name>
    <role>Solutions</role>
  </person>
</root>
```